# Email sent but not received

Tags: codeigniter

The result from email sending is `true` but email is not received. My configs looks like this:

```
$config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 587,
            'smtp_user' => 'tomaivanovtomov@gmail.com',
            'smtp_password' => 'abc9110033969qwe',
            'mailtype' => 'html',
            'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
            'smtp_timeout' => 10,
            'smtp_crypto' => 'tls'
        );
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
```

If I try the other way with `$this->email->initialize($config)` and `$this->load->library('email')` before it, when try to send it I get an error:

```
fsockopen(): unable to connect to smtp.gmail.com:587 (Connection refused)
```

Comment: if these are your real email account settings, you are seriously compromising your account!

Comment: No, it's not. :)

Comment: maybe same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58602315/problem-with-phpmailer-failed-to-connect-to-server/58602534#58602534

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the connection to use `ssl` instead of `tls`, and port `465` instead of `587` :

```php
'smtp_port' => 465,
'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change smtp host with

```
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
```

Check you smtp_port and provide correct your port number with

```
'smtp_port' => 587,
```

And change crypto type with ssl

```
'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl'
```

Answer (score 0):

- try to do it in following order.

  ```
      $this->load->library('email');

      $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
      $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
      $config['smtp_user'] = 'abcdef@gmail.com'; //your email address
      $config['smtp_pass'] = 'testingmails'; // password
      $config['smtp_port'] = 465; 
      $config['smtp_timeout'] = 5;
      $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
      $config['wrapchars'] = 76;
      $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
      $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
      $config['validate'] = FALSE;
      $config['priority'] = 3;
      $config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
      $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
      $config['bcc_batch_mode'] = FALSE;
      $config['bcc_batch_size'] = 200;

      $this->email->initialize($config);
  ```